# How can one use the logarithm function to define angles?

Tags: geometry, complex-analysis, analytic-geometry

In dealing with the complex logarithm function, I read that the imaginary part of $\log w$, is also called the argument of $w$, $\operatorname{arg }w$, and it is interpreted geometrically as the angle between the positive real axis and the half line from the origin through the point $w$.

Using the interpretation, is there a standard way to define angles in triangles in the plane?
I tried to draw a crude little picture.

[image]

So something like $\Im(\log b)-\Im(\log a)$ would give the angle between the two dashed lines emanating out to $b$ and $a$, but how would one define the angle between the legs $ab$ and $ac$? I would like to avoid angles greater than $\pi$, so I'm hoping there's a definition that returns angles in $[0,\pi]$. Thanks.

Comment: What if you look at $c - a$ and $b - a$?

Comment: @DylanMoreland Ok, so a good formula is $\Im(\log(c-a))-\Im(\log(b-a))$? Is there a good way to mod out by $\pi$ to get values in $[0,\pi]$? I don't want to accidentally mod out and get $\pi=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $\text{Im} \log \left(\frac{c-a}{b-a}\right)$, using the principal branch of the logarithm (the one with the imaginary part in $(-\pi, \pi]$).  The result is positive if leg $ac$ is counterclockwise from leg $ab$ and negative if it is clockwise.  If you don't care whether it's clockwise or counterclockwise, take $\left|\text{Im} \log \left(\frac{c-a}{b-a}\right)\right|$.

Comment: This is related to [this formula](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcTan2/27/01/01/0001/).